# How to auto refresh SQL query in R Studio

Tags: rstudio

Good day,
Im new to R studio and still learning,I get data from SQL with a query now I want the query to run in the background automatically so that the shiny app have the latest data at all times how to go about that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `invalidateLater`. Just place it in some reactive context, which you want to be refreshed, and set the time in milliseconds. After the time the reactive will invalidate itself and the results will be refreshed.

Comment: Here is the official documentation: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/invalidateLater.html

Comment: So must I add this on the server side?

Comment: Yes it should be placed inside server side, inside the body of some observer or reactive. For example `observe()` , `reactive()` or `renderPlot()`.